# Load database data into asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

I would like to know how to load data from a database into a asp.net form.

So I use code to get the data via a query "`Select * From ... Where ... = ...`"

Then I load it into a reader and

```
While (reader.read)
{   string sProductName = Convert.ToString(reader[1]);
    /*
    Now I need to display this name and all the other data 
    (selling price, etc) on the form
    But as I do not know how many products there will be it (the form) has to change 
    as the database information does (more products get added or removed). 
    */
}
```

I do not know how to do that last part. How to make the data found display on screen.

Thanks !

The data I need to display is a the Product Name, the Product Description and the Product Selling Price underneath headings with those names thats all.

Comment: The ASP.NET Control for Gidview, <asp:GridView /> based on your requirement.

Comment: You may have to be specific as on what's the data like and How you want to display that.

Comment: Yes I have tried googling but I could only get code that you use in the source code area. @Venkat the problem I am having is that I cannot use <p></p> etc in the form.load section as it does not accept it. I need some code that will allow me to enter html code in the form.load code section.

Comment: you should have the runat="server" attribute specified on the form and your <p> </p> element. You can later, access that on the server code Page.FindContol(IdOfYourElement).

Comment: Hi, ok I think that will work I am going to try it thanks

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Database,

Take gridview control  with id="gridview1" (whatever you like but use same id in code)

```
    SqlConnection sql= new SqlConnection("your data base connection");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from your_table_name", sql);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

        gridview1.DataSource = ds;
        gridview1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I would like to not display it in a gridview but rather just line for line.

Comment: Do you need to get the values from database,or show the values from database

Comment: I need to get the values and then show them, your code would work but I just want to display the information in reader[1], etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
         SqlConnection sql= new SqlConnection("your data base connection");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from your_table_name", sql);
        sql.open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Textbox1.Text=dr[0].ToString();
            Textbox2.Text=dr[1].ToString();
            Textbox3.Text=dr[2].ToString();
            ......................;

        }
      con.close();
```

**NOTE:**

```
      While working with datareader sql connection must be open.
```

I use textboxes to show the values.You can use where ever it is necessary .dr[0].ToString(),.dr[1].ToString() .....Contains the values of database table

Comment: Thanks, but how will I know how any textboxes to have because the amount of products will always be changing as new products get added onto the database and others deleted. If there is code to create a textbox or a label then I could use that.

Comment: Sorry I cant understand your actual problem .will you put the code which you exactly want in picture.I just give an idea for your doubt.